# php recursive function return array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, return

Here is the original function (recursive function):

```
function permute($items, $perms = array()) 
{
    if (empty($items)) 
    { 
        echo join('', $perms).'<br>';
    }  
    else 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); ++$i) 
        {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             $foo = implode(array_splice($newitems, $i, 1));
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             permute($newitems, $newperms);
        }
    }
}
permute(array("A", 'B', 'C'));
```

In this case, the output will be:

```
cba
bca
cab
acb
bac
abc
```

How to modify this part:

```
if (empty($items)) 
{ 
    echo join('', $perms).'<br>';
}
```

change it to return array of string instead of directly echo in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ([IdeOne example](https://ideone.com/yRZxWE)):

```
function permute($items, $perms = array(), $result = array()) 
{
if (empty($items)) 
{ 
    $result[] = join('', $perms);
}  
else 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); ++$i) 
    {
         $newitems = $items;
         $newperms = $perms;
         $foo = implode(array_splice($newitems, $i, 1));
         array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
         $result = permute($newitems, $newperms, $result);
    }
}
return $result;
}
$bar = permute(array("A", 'B', 'C'));

var_dump($bar);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.